# php artisan vendor publish not working

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 5.5 and install

```
composer require roumen/feed
```

I try to load file vendor in my ressource folder for change pagination code. When i try the php artisan like this

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

it is no working.

**FeedController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FeedController extends Controller
{
    public function articles()
    {
        $feed = app()->make('feed');

        $feed->setCache(1,'laravel.feed.article');

        if(! $feed->isCached() ) {
            $articles = Article::latest()->take(10)->get();

            foreach ($articles as $article) {
                $feed->add($article->title,$article->user->name, url($article->path()),$article->created_at , strip_tags($article->description) , strip_tags($article->body));
            }
        }

        return $feed->render('rss');
    }
}
```

my blade

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="فید مقالات راکت" href="/feed/articles">
```

But i run http://localhost:8000/feed/articles similar under image.

[Simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPqgF.png)

Comment: "it is no working." ... is not very compelling

Comment: Can you see any error?

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: i see no error.  Instead of theme show tags.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean??? Are the resources copied to your resources/vendor folder?

Comment: yes it is copied

Comment: Also, there should be no need to `vendor:publish` if you want to change the pagination code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from the [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/roumen/feed)

Register this service provider with Laravel :

```
Roumen\Feed\FeedServiceProvider::class,
```

and add class alias :

```
'Feed' => Roumen\Feed\Feed::class,
```

Publish package views (OPTIONAL) :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Roumen\Feed\FeedServiceProvider"
```